# Why does changing the currency on my api call make the data retrieved not accurate?

Tags: python, api, currency, stock, twelvedata

I am trying to get an api to send me data in GBP instead of USD however when I tried the api sent over the wrong values.

`https://api.twelvedata.com/time_series?symbol=aapl&interval=1week&start_date=2021-03-01&outputsize=5000&apikey={TDKEY}`
this is the api call that returns the data in USD the data retrieved seems correct.

`https://api.twelvedata.com/time_series?symbol=aapl&interval=1week&start_date=2021-03-01&outputsize=5000&apikey={TDKEY}&format=JSON&dp=2&exchange=LSE&currency=GBP`
this is what i added to try and make it return the values in GBP instead.

however the data sent back is not at all what the values should be in GBP, there is no way AAPL is £510. This is what it returns:

{'meta': {'symbol': 'AAPL', 'interval': '1week', 'currency': 'GBp', 'exchange_timezone': 'Europe/London', 'exchange': 'LSE', 'mic_code': 'XLON', 'type': 'Common Stock'}, 'values': [{'datetime': '2023-04-10', 'open': '510.67', 'high': '525.25', 'low': '510.67', 'close': '525.25', 'volume': '248'}, {'datetime': '2023-04-03', 'open': '522.38', 'high': '522.38', 'low': '522.38', 'close': '522.38', 'volume': '0'}, {'datetime': '2023-03-27', 'open': '525.75', 'high': '525.75', 'low': '525.75', 'close': '525.75', 'volume': '26000'}, {'datetime': '2023-03-20', 'open': '513.25', 'high': '513.25', 'low': '513.25', 'close': '513.25', 'volume': '22880'}, {'datetime': '2023-03-13', 'open': '506.50', 'high': '506.50', 'low': '504.50', 'close': '504.50', 'volume': '5740'}, {'datetime': '2023-02-27', 'open': '497.15', 'high': '497.15', 'low': '497.15', 'close': '497.15', 'volume': '0'}, {'datetime': '2023-02-13', 'open': '493.30', 'high': '493.30', 'low': '493.30', 'close': '493.30', 'volume': '659'}, {'datetime': '2023-02-06', 'open': '499.90', 'high': '499.90', 'low': '499.90', 'close': '499.90', 'volume': '0'}, {'datetime': '2023-01-30', 'open': '462.80', 'high': '511.25', 'low': '462.70', 'close': '511.25', 'volume': '169'}, {'datetime': '2023-01-23', 'open': '460.50', 'high': '460.50', 'low': '460.50', 'close': '460.50', 'volume': '0'}, {'datetime': '2023-01-16', 'open': '455.00', 'high': '455.00', 'low': '455.00', 'close': '455.00', 'volume': '0'}, {'datetime': '2023-01-09', 'open': '429.15', 'high': '432.40', 'low': '429.15', 'close': '432.40', 'volume': '0'}, {'datetime': '2022-12-12', 'open': '455.00', 'high': '455.00', 'low': '438.05', 'close': '438.05', 'volume': '148'}, {'datetime': '2022-12-05', 'open': '464.65', 'high': '464.65', 'low': '464.65', 'close': '464.65', 'volume': '0'}, {'datetime': '2022-11-28', 'open': '477.20', 'high': '483.70', 'low': '472.55', 'close': '472.55', 'volume': '1600'}, {'datetime': '2022-11-07', 'open': '486.30', 'high': '492.75', 'low': '486.30', 'close': '492.75', 'volume': '15'}, {'datetime': '2022-09-26', 'open': '548.25', 'high': '553.75', 'low': '505.38', 'close': '505.38', 'volume': '2450'}, {'datetime': '2022-09-12', 'open': '512.00', 'high': '520.50', 'low': '512.00', 'close': '520.50', 'volume': '0'}, {'datetime': '2022-09-05', 'open': '533.00', 'high': '545.00', 'low': '526.25', 'close': '535.50', 'volume': '176'}], 'status': 'ok'}

Comment: According to the documentation, `currency` is not a valid input parameter for a `time_series` request.  So it looks like it's just ignoring that parameter.

Comment: how to ask a good question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask